# Inconsistent member offset computation in MFC class

Tags: c++, mfc, offset, visual-studio-6

In our VS2013 MFC Project, the CWinApp application class has a CWordArray member.

Looking at the dissassembly we can tell that the offset of this member is 21Eh.

This is the call to SetSize assembly code called from within the CwinApp:

```
m_arrayDefInd.SetSize(64, 1);
00F36D0F  push        1  
00F36D11  push        40h  
00F36D13  mov         ecx,dword ptr [this]  
00F36D16  add         ecx,21Eh  <<<<<< NOTE OFFSET
00F36D1C  call        CWordArray::SetSize (0FC25E0h)
```

However, in a CView class, we retrieve the CwinApp pointer and reference this same member. When we look at the dissassembly code in the CView class, the compiler has set the offset at 230h.

```
CMyApp *pApp = (CMyApp *)AfxGetApp();

int size = pApp->m_arrayDefInd.GetSize();
00F2DA42  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-20h]  
00F2DA45  add         ecx,230h  <<<<<< NOTE OFFSET  
00F2DA4B  call        CWordArray::GetSize (0FC225Ch)  
00F2DA50  mov         dword ptr [ebp-24h],eax
```

We have done the obvious – clean, rebuild all. We have ensured both compilation units are using the same application header file.

The above was ported from a VS6 application that handles this correctly.

We're at a loss to explain the above. Can anyone help?

Comment: Just guessing here, but it could possibly be because of virtual inheritance? In the first example `this` is probably the actual class, while in the second case `pApp` is a pointer to a virtual base class. Two different classes, two different offsets.

Comment: In the code you posted, you seem to use `SetSize` in the first and `GetSize` in the second. Is that relevant? Perhaps you could explain the actual problem you're seeing - all of this stuff should be opaque in normal use.

Comment: I don't think it's safe to assume that `dword ptr [this]` is exactly the same value as `dword ptr [ebp-20h]`. What exactly is the content of `ecx` when the call is made? And please call the same method in each example `GetSize()` or `SetSize()`.